# Rerendering a component after onClick - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a booking system, when you click a button with classname "greenButton" it meets the condition of "yellowButton" the problem being i have to refresh the page for react to rerender is there any best practices regarding this?

```js
const renderTableData = () => {
  let id = 1;
  return (
    <tr>
      {days.map((val) => (
        <td>
          {timeSlot.map((time, i) => {
            let buttonId = id++;
            if (myBookings().result.includes(id)) {
              console.log('mybooking');
              return (
                <button id={buttonId} className="yellowButton">
                  {time}
                </button>
              );
            } else if (occupiedSlots().result.includes(id)) {
              console.log('occupied');
              return (
                <button id={buttonId} className="redButton">
                  {time}
                </button>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <button
                  id={buttonId}
                  className="greenButton"
                  onClick={() => {
                    canBookSlot({ id: buttonId });
                  }}
                >
                  {time} {buttonId}
                </button>
              );
            }
          })}
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
};
```

I imagine i could insert something in `canBookSlot()`?

```js
const canBookSlot = (id) => {
  if (userDetailsObj.canBook != 0) {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/book/week1/ex', {
      room: userDetailsObj.room,
      id: id.id + 1,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: click a button with `classname "greenButton"` it meets the condition of `"yellowButton"` ?. What do you mean by meets, what are you trying to achieve??.

Comment: can you provide us userDetailsObj complete properties?

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal I would like to run the conditional rendering again after a button has been clicked because the outcome will change.

Comment: @yohanes `{room: 'GH1209', canBook: 0, hasBooked: 1}`

Comment: You can use `useState` hook whenever you will  change the outcome or state, react will automatically render the component.